# Bootstrap 3.3.7 modal open and jump to top

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

When I open modal in Bootstrap 3.3.7 it jumps to top of page.

I am using Bootstrap JS 3.3.7 from official CDN

```
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

I have already tried with CSS solutions like this, but doesn´t works for me

```
body.modal-open {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Here is URL of my webapp in production to can see the behavior of Boostrap modal.
[My webapp with modal issue](https://www.xadani.com.mx/producto/camara-analogica-punta-de-poste-27x-zoom-ip66-exterior.html)

[Button with modal problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCn1K.png)

Comment: `.modal-open{ position: relative; }`

Worked for me =)

Comment: Can you explain more, what are you trying to do. Are you trying to remove the scroll from the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to remove the scroll from modal. This could be your solution.

Few things you can do about your modal

1. Too much of content in modal(Remove element that are not needed)
2. Change the padding(over write bootstrap css with your custom CSS)
3. Change the height of textarea.
4. Add `modal-lg` class to `your modal-dialog <div>`

eg : `<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">`

5. Added some sample css that can help you out in removing scroll.

Added a screenshot at last, on how it will look after doing all above changes.

Bootstrap model : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals

```css
//Changing the margin of dialog
.modal-dialog {
    margin: 5px auto;
}

//removing extra padding from the body
.modal-body {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

// Add padding to your footer
.modal .modal-footer {
    border-top: none;
    padding: 10px;
}

// change height of textarea
textarea.form-control {
    height: 100px !important;
}
```

[image: bootstrap modal with no scroll]

Comment: you can also add modal-dialog-centered to your modal-dialog <div> to vertically center it.